# I can't show chart using pyplot

Tags: python

My current code is :

```
xpoints = np.array([0, 1])
ypoints = np.array([10, 100])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Are you doing this in a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: The code is correct but it may not be allowed to show it. For instance, if you run on a remote computer. You must provide detail where do you run your script. It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two  lines to make your compiler able to draw:

```
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```